# Ayuda con campo Saldo en una tabla tipo vista

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Tengo una tabla con estos campos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito crear una tabla de tipo vista donde exista una columna adicional llamada Saldo. La función de esta columna es sumar o restar el valor de la columna monto en base a si el valor de NUM es 1 o 2 (Si es 1 suma, si es 2 resta). (Estos datos son de ejemplo, pueden ser cualquier otros datos dependiendo de lo que capture el usuario) Tengo el siguiente código con el cual he logrado hacer la función anterior pero no de la mejor forma.

```
    SELECT 
    R.INDICE,
    R.ID,
    R.NUM,
    R.MONTO,
        SUM(
        D.MONTO *
        CASE 
            WHEN D.NUM=2 THEN -1 
            ELSE 1
        END
       ) [SALDO]
FROM TABLA R
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLA D
    ON R.ID = D.ID AND R.INDICE >= D.INDICE
GROUP BY R.INDICE,R.ID,R.NUM,R.MONTO
```

El resultado que obtengo es el siguiente: Lo que puedo identificar es que el campo saldo no se calcula bien cuando hay dos egresos consecutivos, pero después el saldo se corrige.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La columna en rojo es la manera correcta como debería calcularse esa columna.  Alguna sugerencia sobre qué podría estar haciendo mal?

Actualización:

Apliqué la sugerencia de Lamak a mi código más sin embargo la columna saldo sigue mostrándose mal calculada:

```
SELECT * FROM VistaPrueba A
```

OUTER APPLY (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Num = 2 THEN -1 ELSE 1 END * MontoUsar) SALDO
             FROM VistaPrueba
             WHERE IDCTA = A.IDCTA
             AND INDICE <= A.INDICE) B;

Resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si creo una nueva tabla y le capturo los mismos datos que la vista, la columna saldo se muestra correctamente.

```
SELECT *
```

FROM dbo.Prueba A
OUTER APPLY (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN NUM = 2 THEN -1 ELSE 1 END * MONTO) SALDO
             FROM dbo.Prueba
             WHERE ID = A.ID
             AND INDICE <= A.INDICE) B;

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Porque tienes la columna Saldo como parte de tu select?  Que es lo que contiene esa columna?

Comment: Gracias por la observación, la puse por error. La columna la genero en el select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En vez de un `LEFT JOIN` creo que deberías usar un `OUTER APPLY`:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.TuTabla A
OUTER APPLY (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN NUM = 2 THEN -1 ELSE 1 END * MONTO) SALDO
             FROM dbo.TuTabla
             WHERE ID = A.ID
             AND INDICE <= A.INDICE) B
;
```

[**Acá hay un demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ed7b8fdb5b64ac6d3b3cd5f7983b7c13) de esta consulta. Y los resultados son:

```
╔════════╦════╦═════╦═══════╦═══════╗
║ INDICE ║ ID ║ NUM ║ MONTO ║ SALDO ║
╠════════╬════╬═════╬═══════╬═══════╣
║      4 ║  4 ║   1 ║   100 ║   100 ║
║      5 ║  4 ║   2 ║     0 ║   100 ║
║      6 ║  4 ║   2 ║   100 ║     0 ║
║      7 ║  4 ║   1 ║   100 ║   100 ║
║      8 ║  4 ║   1 ║   200 ║   300 ║
║      9 ║  4 ║   2 ║  1000 ║  -700 ║
╚════════╩════╩═════╩═══════╩═══════╝
```

Comment: Agradezco tu respuesta Lamak. Funciona la solución que me brindaste más sin embargo tengo un detalle muy extraño. Si genero la consulta desde mi tabla(Que cabe aclarar es una tabla tipo vista) obtengo el mismo resultado inicial con el saldo mal calculado. Pero si hago una tabla nueva (No de tipo vista) y capturo exactamente los mismos datos, la columna de saldo se calcula correctamente. A qué pudiese deberse? Actualizo mi pregunta.